# SELinux is denying access to create a file, but comparing all selinux settings shows no problems

Tags: permissions, access-control-list, selinux

I have two Centos 7 systems that should be identical (other than data).

I have a server process on server A that is being denied write access to a particular directory. The denial shows up as an SELinux denial.

On server B, the same service is not being denied write access to the same directory.

I've compared file perms, directory perms, ACLs, and SELinux contexts between both servers and they appear identical -- except for that A gets the "denied" error and B does not.

As a workaround I set SELinux to "Permissive" and now the server process on A can write to the directory.

At this point, I'm really just looking for ideas of what else I can troubleshoot; I'm happy to provide technical details if required. I am pretty experienced generally with Linux administration but not very experienced specifically with SELinux, so at this point I'm stumped.

*Edit -- tech details*

The service I've been having trouble with is IPA. Actually, though, it is Apache, as bundled with IPA, not being allowed to write to the memcached dir. Specifically, user "apache" is being denied write access to "/var/run/ipa_memcached/".

Here are commands I ran which came back literally identically between servers (except PIDs). (These were run as root, so lines starting with "$" are the command, what follows is the output)

```
$ semanage fcontext -l | grep memc
/var/run/memcached(/.*)?                           all files          system_u:object_r:memcached_var_run_t:s0
/var/run/ipa_memcached(/.*)?                       all files          system_u:object_r:memcached_var_run_t:s0
/usr/bin/memcached                                 regular file       system_u:object_r:memcached_exec_t:s0
/etc/rc\.d/init\.d/memcached                       regular file       system_u:object_r:memcached_initrc_exec_t:s0

$ ls -ldZ /var/run/ipa_memcached/; ls -lZ /var/run/ipa_memcached/
drwx------. apache apache system_u:object_r:memcached_var_run_t:s0 /var/run/ipa_memcached/
srwx------. apache apache system_u:object_r:memcached_var_run_t:s0 ipa_memcached
-rw-r--r--. apache apache system_u:object_r:memcached_var_run_t:s0 ipa_memcached.pid

$ sudo -u apache id -Z
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023

$ ps auxZ | grep http
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    apache   12321  0.0  6.6 674224 124860 ?       Sl   19:07   0:06 (wsgi:ipa)      -DFOREGROUND
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    apache   12322  0.0  1.3 324060 26040 ?        S    19:07   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    kdcproxy 12319  0.0  1.2 628032 23604 ?        Sl   19:07   0:00 (wsgi:kdcproxy) -DFOREGROUND
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    kdcproxy 12320  0.0  1.2 628032 23604 ?        Sl   19:07   0:00 (wsgi:kdcproxy) -DFOREGROUND
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    root     12314  0.0  1.3 298704 24652 ?        Ss   19:07   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    root     12318  0.0  0.5  53880 11096 ?        S    19:07   0:00 /usr/libexec/nss_pcache 4423694 off /etc/httpd/alias
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 root 17615 0.0  0.0 112648 972 pts/0 R+ 21:11   0:00 grep --color=auto http

$ find /var/run/ipa* | xargs getfacl
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/run/ipa
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
other::---

# file: var/run/ipa/services.list
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

# file: var/run/ipa/renewal.lock
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::---
other::---

# file: var/run/ipa_memcached
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rwx
group::---
other::---

# file: var/run/ipa_memcached/ipa_memcached.pid
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

# file: var/run/ipa_memcached/ipa_memcached
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
```

**edit** Found the problem

`audit2why` showed me what was actually causing my problems

```
grep jsilverman /var/log/audit/audit.log* | grep denied| audit2why
...
/var/log/audit/audit.log.1:type=AVC msg=audit(1471293346.098:440365): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=13668 comm="httpd" name="krbcc_A_jsilverman" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:memcached_var_run_t:s0 tclass=file

Was caused by:
The boolean httpd_manage_ipa was set incorrectly.
Description:
Allow httpd to manage ipa

Allow access by executing:
# setsebool -P httpd_manage_ipa 1
... (and more, similar messages) ...
```

This led to compare selinux settings

Server A

```
$ getsebool  -a| grep httpd_manage_ipa
httpd_manage_ipa --> off
```

Server B

```
$ getsebool  -a| grep httpd_manage
httpd_manage_ipa --> on
```

Now, how could that have happened? Also, how can I clone selinux settings from B->A?

Comment: Is auditd running and what `denied` messages do you see in it?

Comment: yes; will edit with that content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer by any means, but what do you see as output from audit2why or audit2allow if they are available? Do they specify the modules that may need to be updated to allow the access?

Comment: It may say something on the lines of httpd_network_write or something similar. You can check the current value using getsebool-a |grep http.

Comment: THANKS. This was it -- I really don't know how to use selinux, so I'm not aware of the tooling around it. `audit2why` answered my questions and found what's different between the "identically configured" systems. Now, how can I reset the selinux settings back to their "working" state?

Comment: On Server A, while being the super user, do the following on the shell:  setsebool-P httpd_manage_ipa 1  Now, unfortunately, I am not 100% certain whether or not it will allow the process to write to the directory it was trying to write to.   I saw the below bug via a Google search, is this similar to what you noticed?  https://fedorahosted.org/freeipa/ticket/2432

Comment: That -P is to mark the Boolean as a permanent change so that it persists across reboots.

Comment: Doing `setsebool -P ...` for the booleans that were not in sync with the working server fixed this issue for me; and yes, it persisted across reboot